# How can i perfectly Pass Processed frames to Display?

Tags: kotlin, android-camera2, google-mlkit, pose-detection

I'm using Camera2 Libray with MLkit's PoseDetection in Android Studio but input frames are causing crash, as they are unable to process by model as they are coming in and output are not being displayed, its just a black Screen.
BufferQueueProducer errors: These errors suggest that the buffer queue producer attempted to exceed the maximum dequeued buffer count. This might indicate a problem with managing buffer counts efficiently, potentially related to the rendering or display process.
This is current error i'm facing.

I have tried Reducing resolution of frames.
I have aslo tried reducing input frames by adding delay in between frames i.e. taking 12 fps
Still the error is occuring and i want solution for it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.